# mysql php query list and sorting

Tags: php, mysql, list, numbers

This will probably too easy but I cant find the answer. I have a list made by a mysql query, but I want to only show like X results and then have some button to show the next 5 etc. How do I make that?

P.S: I guess it would be similar, but how do change the sort without making another query?

Comment: Can you show what you've done so far?

Comment: the term you are looking for is "pagination".

Comment: yeah pagination. All I can find is scripts that simply broke my template. I only have a mysql while that fetch results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for example your query is

```
    $add=5*(int)$_GET['page'];
    $first=$add;
    $second=$add+5;
    $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 'tbl' LIMIT $first,$second");
    while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc()){
         echo $row['test'];
    }
```

So if you want to get rows between 5,10 then you have to add 5 with both,
if you send this request : localhost/index.php?page=2 then you will have this query;

```
    $query=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM 'tbl' LIMIT 10,15");
```

If you want to use top then it is like this : SELECT TOP 10 FROM 'tblUser' ORDER BY topscore;